# Not able to get which php.ini is used

Tags: apache, php

I am using apache 2.2 webserver (win 7 32,php 5.2 ) . trying to run php file in apache

i have added following statement in httpd.conf under apache conf dir to make php file run under apache (ref: http://goo.gl/jxKI)

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php-5.2.6-Win32/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

things are working fine i am able to run php file under apache

Now i want to make some changes to php.ini but can't locate which php.ini file is being used. tried with my php.ini in php installation folder C:/Program Files/PHP/php-5.2.6-Win32/php.ini but this file is also no used.

```
phpinfo() gives path as c:\windows but there is no php.ini 
echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'); doesn't return anything
```

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: perhaps it is in c:\windows but hidden. I assume windows has a file search option somewhere

Comment: <appending content> Loaded Configuration File in phpinfo() call shows (none) as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> phpinfo() gives path as c:\windows but there is no php.ini

This means your .dll expects the configuration file in `c:\windows`.
Your tutorial mistakenly advises to create a configuration file in `c:\php\php.ini`. Move it to `c:\windows`, edit it to your liking, and it should work fine.

I would advise a beginner who seeks to learn PHP/Apache to use ready-to-use packages at first, such as [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Manual installations require deeper understanding of PHP (and Apache to some extent).

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function:

[php_ini_loaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php)

Comment: it returns nothing. does it means no php.ini file loaded

Comment: according to docs:  "The loaded php.ini path, or === FALSE if one is not loaded."

Answer (score 1):

This is because PHP can run *without* a php.ini file.

Your Windows package (actually I think all bundles come with it) should come with these two files:

- `php.ini-development`
- `php.ini-production`

Renaming any of those two to `php.ini` and moving it into the search path (e.g. `c:\windows`) will make PHP load its configuration from that file.

Make sure to restart your Apache after making changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Youu can quickly check via command line (terminal) with this:

```
php -i | grep /php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try phpinfo() function which will list the details of your php variables which apache is using. 
I think you can try this function and it will tell you which php.ini is loaded. 
Or also if you are using your own directory to store your project files, you can use .htaccess to override your module requirement or you can use php function to load your php module. 
Hope it will help you...